# Google chrome browser is misbehaving

Tags: google-chrome

I don't know what's going wrong with my chrome browser. Everything was working fine but all of a sudden the width from my css styling for divs, input elements and all other widths are disorganised. I don't know if its the width that increased or the padding or margin but what I know is that everything is disorganised. But I checked firefox and other browsers everything is okay. I cleared my cache and cookie but no solution. Please does anyone knows how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you run the chrome browser cleanup tool? Could be a bug

Comment: Yes and it says no program found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the silly solution. The browser was zoomed to `120%` unknown to me so I adjusted it back to `100%`